# ActiveMq Queue's with server

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic

Can I achieve the functionality of Client and server using activemq queues...

There should be clients which creates messages and send to a particular queue and the server should listen to this messages and send to appropriate client(queue).

Urgently needed help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message queuing is just a means for communication, even though it's used more in Server to server communication it's suitable in other scenarios as well.

If all peers (servers and clients) connects to a central ActiveMQ broker (perhaps located on the server node).

You just need to model how it's supposed to work, if you should use a a publish/subscribe model or a point to point.

ActiveMQ supports dynamic creation of queues, which is useful when you have clients of any number connecting. You can easily give a queue a name of a unique client ID.

So, basically, yes - this is achievable. Just add the code. ;-)